# How is put_user faster than copy_to_user

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was writing sample programs on character device drivers, i found this on Advanced Character drivers chapter of Oreilly Linux Device Drivers.

```
put_user(datum, ptr)
_ _put_user(datum, ptr)
These macros write the datum to user space; they are relatively fast and should be called instead of copy_to_user whenever single values are being transferred.
```

Can anyone please explain me practically how are these macros faster than copy_to_user.

Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: __put_user() is faster than put_user() because it doesn't validate ptr is access_ok or not, it writes to the ptr as long as it's writable.  Both put_user() and copy_to_user() verify ptr is safe to access before writing to it.  put_user() is used to copy single variable while copy_to_user() is used to copy packed structure/bytes etc.  So if you want to copy a single variable safely then use put_user() otherwise use copy_to_user() instead.

Comment: So you mean while copying four byte of information, both put_user and copy from user takes some time

Comment: put_user() might still be a bit faster than copy_to_user() because its source code is shorter but the difference would be minor.

Comment: How can we measure the number of clock cycles executed by put_user, i measured the difference between the value of jiffie before and after put_user, it is zero

Comment: a jiffies is about 10ms, try trace_printk() [link](https://lwn.net/Articles/365835/), it can trace down to us (0.001ms)